# Showing previous en next month relative to contextual filter (using D7 Date Views)

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-contextual-filters

I have a content type with a date field (start and end date, always covers a whole month), an image and a title. I use a view with a contextual filter to get the month from the URL (that looks like text/2015-10, text/2015-09, ...). Contextual filter: Content: Month - start date (field_month). Granularity is set to month.

I want to make a view block for the previous month and one for the next month. And that is previous or next to the month i get from the contextual filter. I want to use these blocks as a pager to the previous or next month, relative to the month i get from the URL with the contextual filter. Not relative to today.

For a simple pager with the text '<< prev' and 'next >>', I can use pager: Page by date | Position: bottom, format: clean.
But that only gives text, I want to show the title and thumbnail from my view as my pager. But to achieve that, I need 'next month' and 'previous month' relative to the month from my contextual filter.

Is this possible with Date / Date Views ?? Am I missing something?

Comment: please let us know what have you tried so far. May be code sample will be a good idea

Comment: I've tried a normal views filter for my field_month, set to 'Is equal to' Relative date 'previous month'. But that is relative to today, not to the date from the contextual filter.

I'm tried the modules Free Pager (https://www.drupal.org/project/freepager) and Previous/Next API (https://www.drupal.org/project/prev_next), but those don't work for a previous / next view, only for nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one should be on [drupal.stackexchange.com](http://drupal.stackexchange.com), but anyways:

1. Create a custom block with `hook_block_info()` and `hook_block_view()`
2. Extract the date from the URL using `explode('/', request_path())`
3. Adjust the date in code to DATE-1M
4. In your `hook_block_view()`, set
   the output to `views_embed_view('VIEW_NAME', 'DISPLAY_ID',
   'CHANGED_DATE')` where:

   1. VIEW_NAME = machine name of the view
   2. DISPLAY_NAME = machine name of the display (usually block_1 or sth)
   3. CHANGED_DATE = the string containing the adjusted date

Comment: Ow, I'm sorry. I will ask it on drupal.stackexhange.com (I thought it was linked when I tagged this with Drupal).


I have no experience with `hook_block_info()` and `hook_block_view()`, but I will look into it. Thanks.